# Problem in finding server name for connecting Power BI with MySql DataBase

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to make a connection of PowerBI with Mysql database. I am not able to find the server name required for connection.

I tried localhost as server name but I need to connect to the live server. Hence that didn't work.

I have connected PowerBI with the local host using wampserver positively.

I have watched this Youtube tutorial :-

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggpn3-4FB4s&t=1s
```

I want to know how to find the server name as shown in the above video.